# What's this 't' unit on a PCB?

Tags: pcb, identification, units

I recently came across a symbol like this on a PCB: (forgive the use of Paint)

[image: the symbol]

The component was marked as being 0.1 (symbol).

You can just make it out in the centre of this photo:

[image: the photo]

It's a capacitor, so I'm guessing it's perhaps measuring farads, but surely then an F would have been used... What is it measuring?

Comment: セ looks like a "se" symbol in Katakana (Japanese syllabary). No idea what it means in this context though.

Comment: Where did you find the PCB, what is its function?

Comment: Just a thought: it could be used to indicate a ceramic capacitor.

Comment: BTW, in case you actually care about the electronics rather than the Japanese, that's certainly a 0.1uF capacitor, not 0.1F.

Comment: Funny, I am looking at a Japanese PCB with the exact same mark, 0.1 (セ), above a resistor.

Comment: Actually, it's probably a capacitor that looks like a resistor... I've just posted my own question. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/591071

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I am thinking that セ is used by the Japanese as shorthand for セラミック (ceramic). That is a ceramic disk capacitor, of course.

セラミック is a Katakana transliteration of the English word ceramic, and sounds like cer-ram-ique-ah.

Comment: It's not uncommon for the first character of Chinese and Japanese words to be used as shorthand- for example the provincial shorthand used in Chinese car license plates- eg. 黑 (black) is used for 黑龙江省 (black dragon river province = Heilongjiang Province).

Answer (score 5):

That is the Japanese katakana letter `セ` (se). As for why it's next to a "コンデンサ" I couldn't tell you (since my Japanese jargon is still very weak).

Comment: The Japanese sure love their German. "ko-n-de-n-sa" would be short for German "Kondensator" (capacitor).

Comment: Capacitors used to be called "condensers" in English as well.