# Identify a pink axial resistor or capacitor marked 0.1 (セ)

Tags: pcb, identification

Can someone help me identify the pink component in this photo?

This appears on a Yamaha PortaSound PSS-480 PCB.

You can barely see in the photo, but underneath the component is printed
–—||—–

If it's a ceramic capacitor, what's the capacitance/voltage and what can it be replaced with?

[image: a pink axial component marked 0.1 (セ)]

Comment: If you don’t know what it is, why do you want to replace it?

Comment: There's another one on the other side of the board that's burnt to a crisp.

Comment: Before replacing it, ask yourself why it is burnt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably this is a 100 nF ±10% (min:90, max:110 nF). The service manual is available for this device in the network.

The [Capacitor Color Code Calculator](https://www.dcode.fr/capacitor-color-code) help you get proper value for this component.

In your case:

- 1st Color: Significant digit -> Brown
- 2nd Color: Significant digit -> Black
- 3th Color: Multipler -> Yellow
- 4th Color: Tolerance -> Silver

Comment: Ah - 100 nF = 0.1 µF, as marked?

Comment: Yes, it should be a correct value for this component

Comment: In addition, the symbol after the capacitor value means it's a "semiconductive ceramic capacitor" while the other capacitors that don't have this symbol are just "ceramic capacitor". Basically those Class III type caps are so obsolete that simply standard Class II type 100nF ceramic is a better replacement.

Comment: Thanks all - I replaced this with a 100nF 50v bipolar capacitor and it's working fine so far.